# Yum downgrade when the newer release has an extra RPM

Tags: rpm, yum, downgrade

In the latest release I have added a new RPM. During upgrade from an older version, it works fine because I have added dependency in the spec file of the main RPM.

Here is the dependency tree:

```
Older release:
RPM1 depends on RPM2

Newer release:
RPM1 depends on RPM2 and RPM3
RPM3 depends on RPM2
```

Upgrade works just fine when I try `yum upgrade RPM1`. How do I downgrade to the older version? Specifying all the RPMs with `yum downgrade RPM1 RPM2 RPM3` doesn't work. Even `yum downgrade RPM1 and RPM2` does not work because RPM3 now depends on the latest version of RPM3.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to approach this. You might have to go do "behind `yum`'s back" and use `rpm` directly to force erase RPM3 and then you should be able to downgrade RPM1 and RPM2. The other option is to simply uninstall all three and then reinstall the older versions of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (not tested thou):

```
yum swap -- downgrade RPM1 RPM2 -- remove RPM3
```